# Twitter Rest API + J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, twitter

I want to use Twitter rest API for developing J2ME application.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question: What exactly do you want to do with the API in your application?

Answer (score 0):

See this [j2megroup blogshot](http://j2megroup.blogspot.com/2009/11/twitter-api-me-sample-app.html). Here they said clearly how to use twitter with j2me. and also see this [nokia forum](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?186299-login-to-twitter) discussion.

Comment: Thanks I have used Twitter API ME.But the Problem is that I am not receiving AUTH keys from Twitter.That's why I want to use rest API.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Twitter API ME](http://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime/pages/Home).

**From the website:**

> The current three Java platforms
>   supported by Twitter API ME are:
>
> Java Micro Edition (MIDP 2.0 / CLDC
>   1.0) or newer Android 1.1 or newer (also run on Java SE) RIM (Blackberry)

Comment: Thanks I have used Twitter API ME.But the Problem is that I am not receiving AUTH keys from Twitter.That's why I want to use rest API.

Comment: Could you give us the exception if any? Also what problems are you having calling twitter rest api directly?

Comment: Credential c = new Credential("Mudassir25", "rocking", "nNtw3VRRd3aCdKLuJAK9w", "fIt7bmV7zXuMwuUtyR6N1pG2infjK0W4tSgnRM");
            UserAccountManager m = UserAccountManager.getInstance(c);
            if (m.verifyCredential()) {
                //m.verifyCredential();
                Tweet t = new Tweet("Hi!!! This is my first tweet via Twitter API ME.");
                TweetER ter = TweetER.getInstance(m);
                t = ter.post(t);
            }
This code only update Tweet only for "Mudassir25" Twitter ID.And not for other.That's why I request for xAuth key, but not received.